# passing mixed const integer ASCII values and const char array in C and passing const int without previous declaration

Tags: arrays, c, constants, ascii, string-literals

I have 2 parts to this question.

1: If I want to pass a const int array to a function, normally I would do so.

```
const int array[3] = {1,2,3};
somefunction(array,3);
```

But I want to do it in a simpler way like you can do with strings is this possible.

```
somefunction("abc",3);
```

To something like `somefunction({1,2,3},3);` I know this doesn't work but is there a syntactically correct way to do this.

2: If the previous question is possible then this one is answered. Is there a way to mix ascii values in a const string. like...
`somefunction({1,2,3,"test"},7);`  I know this doesn't work but is there a syntactically correct way to do this.

Comment: The above duplicate post is for the first question. I believe the answer to the second one is no, it can't be done. Arrays in C cannot have elements with different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the first your question i can say you can do it using the compound literal.. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    f( ( int[] ) { 1, 2, 3 }, 3 );
}
```

But you can not have an array with elements of different types.

So for such a construction `{1,2,3,"test"}` you need to split the string literal into separate characters like `{1,2,3, 't', 'e', 's', 't'}`

Comment: thank you so much my idea would be like this ```( char[] ) { 1, 2, 'a' }```

Comment: @JesseTaube You can also define the compound literal like  ( int[] ) { 1, 2, 'a' } depending on what you are going to do with the elements.